# Prevent traffic from wlan0 to be routed to the internet via eth0 using iptables

Tags: iptables

I need to restrict traffic on a debian machine, e.g. using IP tables. Specifically, the server has 3 main network interfaces, eth0, wlan0, and tun0.

eth0 is the normal ethernet connection using which the machine connects to the internet
wlan0 is a wifi hotspot, i.e. other devices connect via this interface to the machine
tun0 is an IPSec VPN that connects "through" eth0 to an external VPN server
I need now to restrict all traffic from devices that connect to the machine via wifi (i.e. via wlan0) from accessing the internet. Unfortunately, the external VPN server does not have a fixed IP address.

My plan is hence to allow traffic "coming" from wlan0 ONLY to be forwarded to tun0, but never to eth0. As far as I understand, this should result in all traffic that would not be routed via the VPN connection to be dropped and internet access would be impossible. At the same time, the server itself could access the internet normally.

Is this possible or will this interfere with establishing the VPN connection in the first place?

My idea goes a bit like this using iptables:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP -i wlan0 -o eth0 -p all
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -i eth0 -o wlan0 -p all
```

I also thought of specifying routes in a way that traffic from wlan0 can only be forwarded via tun0 and no other options exist.

Which of the approaches is more reasonable?

Comment: You should add the rule(s) to the `FORWARD` chain, and you don't need `-p all`. `Which of the approaches is more reasonable` They don't really contradict with each other. You always need appropriate routes for routing to work as desired. The iptables filtering rule is for making sure that when you routes have gone wrong (e.g. deleted or overriden for whatever reasons), the traffics won't "leak" to wherever you don't want them to. (People often call this a "kill-switch".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, what I did to succeed here:

I added the respective REJECT rules to the FORWARD chain as suggested by @Tom_Yan:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j REJECT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j REJECT
sudo iptables-save
```

thus effectively cutting all traffic from the wifi network to the "normal" eth0 interface (and vice versa).

This already does the trick. If the vpn breaks down, no wifi client has any form of access to the internet. As soon as the vpn connection is reestablished, internet is available to those clients again. Mission success.